# Buffer overflow when launching program with system()

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, buffer-overflow, webots

I'm currently using UNIX sockets to communicate between my C++ program and Webots (a robotic simulator). However, I've noticed that after some time (1~2 hours), Webots unexpectedly shuts down, without any apparent reason for it (or I just haven't discovered it yet), which kind of screws what I am doing on my C++ program, as I need to constantly send and receive data packets.

So as fail-safe, I implemented something of a *Webots-checker* on my code, using `system()` and `pidof()`:

```
(...)
if (system("pidof -s webots-bin")!=0) system("webots &");
(...)
```

which just checks if there is any process by the name of `webots-bin`, and re-lauches the program if it's not found. However, when this should act (after some hours, when Webots closes), I get a buffer overflow error instead:

```
 *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/local/webots/webots-bin terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7fea104cd5cc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x110560)[0x7fea104cc560]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x10f9e9)[0x7fea104cb9e9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_default_xsputn+0xdb)[0x7fea10438aeb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0xafb)[0x7fea1040632b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__vsprintf_chk+0x94)[0x7fea104cba84]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__sprintf_chk+0x7d)[0x7fea104cb9cd]
/usr/local/webots/webots-    bin(_ZN11WbViewpoint17createOgreObjectsEP22WbOgreRenderingContext+0x58)[0x67c9f8]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin(_ZN7WbGroup17createOgreObjectsEP22WbOgreRenderingContext+0x61)[0x539c71]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin(_ZN8WbView3D8setWorldEP17WbSimulationWorld+0x149)[0x672789]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin(_ZN16WbSimulationView8setWorldEP17WbSimulationWorld+0x26)[0x61d796]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin(_ZN12WbMainWindow23updateAfterWorldLoadingEb+0x2f)[0x592eaf]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin[0x589454]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectPKS_iPPv+0x326)[0x7fea129751b6]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin(_ZN13WbApplication15postWorldLoadedEb+0x30)[0x4c0260]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin(_ZN13WbApplication9loadWorldE7QStringb+0x398)[0x4c3928]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin(_ZN12WbMainWindow11revertWorldEv+0x74)[0x592974]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin[0x5893fd]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN7QObject5eventEP6QEvent+0x38e)[0x7fea1297108e]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget5eventEP6QEvent+0x4f)[0x7fea12f3037f]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN11QMainWindow5eventEP6QEvent+0x7b)[0x7fea1333135b]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0xac)[0x7fea12ed741c]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtGui.so.4(_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x13d)[0x7fea12edf28d]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication14notifyInternalEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x8c)[0x7fea1295e6fc]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate16sendPostedEventsEP7QObjectiP11QThreadData+0x3d3)[0x7fea12962f53]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtCore.so.4(+0x1d2183)[0x7fea12990183]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x135)[0x7fea0f8ddf05]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x49248)[0x7fea0f8de248]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x34)[0x7fea0f8de304]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x73)[0x7fea1298fcc3]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtGui.so.4(+0x2c809e)[0x7fea12f8b09e]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop13processEventsE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x32)[0x7fea1295d2b2]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE+0x164)[0x7fea1295d724]
/usr/local/webots/lib/libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv+0xb9)[0x7fea12963319]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin(main+0x52)[0x681302]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fea103ddea5]
/usr/local/webots/webots-bin[0x4b3fc9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0072e000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 7870974                                /usr/local/webots/webots-bin
0092e000-0092f000 r--p 0032e000 08:12 7870974                                /usr/local/webots/webots-bin
0092f000-00933000 rw-p 0032f000 08:12 7870974                            /usr/local/webots/webots-bin
00933000-00937000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
025c2000-07c2e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fe9ea900000-7fe9f0000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9f0000000-7fe9f0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9f0021000-7fe9f4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9f4034000-7fe9f6034000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9f6034000-7fe9f60b4000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 100827158                  /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7fe9f60b4000-7fe9f6114000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 100761621                  /SYSV00000000     (deleted)
7fe9f6114000-7fe9f65ce000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 100728852                  /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7fe9f65ce000-7fe9f65cf000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9f65cf000-7fe9f6ecf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:24593]
7fe9f6ecf000-7fe9f6fcf000 rw-s 05352000 00:05 1862                       /dev/ati/card0
7fe9f6fcf000-7fe9f78cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9f78cf000-7fe9f7acf000 rw-s 050c0000 00:05 1862                       /dev/ati/card0
7fe9f7acf000-7fe9f7bcf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9f7bcf000-7fe9f7dcf000 rw-s 050bd000 00:05 1862                       /dev/ati/card0
7fe9f7dcf000-7fe9f80d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe9f80d0000-7fe9f8122000 r--p 00000000 08:12 8782802                        /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-B.ttf
7fe9f8122000-7fe9f8134000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 8128035                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
7fe9f8134000-7fe9f8333000 ---p 00012000 08:12 8128035                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
7fe9f8333000-7fe9f8335000 r--p 00011000 08:12 8128035                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
7fe9f8335000-7fe9f8336000 rw-p 00013000 08:12 8128035                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
7fe9f8336000-7fe9f8338000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 265883                     /lib/x86_64-    linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.4
7fe9f8338000-7fe9f8538000 ---p 00002000 08:12 265883                     /lib/x86_64-    linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.4
7fe9f8538000-7fe9f8539000 r--p 00002000 08:12 265883                     /lib/x86_64-    linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.4
7fe9f8539000-7fe9f853a000 rw-p 00003000 08:12 265883                     /lib/x86_64-        linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.4
7fe9f853a000-7fe9f8541000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 7740965                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7fe9f8541000-7fe9f8740000 ---p 00007000 08:12 7740965                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7fe9f8740000-7fe9f8741000 r--p 00006000 08:12 7740965                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7fe9f8741000-7fe9f8742000 rw-p 00007000 08:12 7740965                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7fe9f8742000-7fe9f8745000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 265848                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7fe9f8745000-7fe9f8944000 ---p 00003000 08:12 265848                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7fe9f8944000-7fe9f8945000 r--p 00002000 08:12 265848                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
7fe9f8945000-7fe9f8946000 rw-p 00003000 08:12 265848                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1Aborted (core dumped)
```

Using `system()` to launch and close Webots from the programs works, however seems to fail at the moment in question, perharps because the way Webots is closed?

EDIT: The same thing happens when forking the program and using `execlp` to launch Webots, but not if I periodically close and reopen. From the backtrace (which I've added) I reckon the problem is within Webots binaries, but that's as far as my knowledge goes. Is there any way to prevent such buffer overflows?

Comment: Are you sure the buffer overflow is in your program, and not in the executed program? You should really study the backtrace properly.

Comment: "Webots unexpectedly shuts down, without any apparent reason for it". So run it in gdb/your preferred debugger.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Indeed the problem seems to be coming from the executed program, but how do I find the cause?

Comment: Run a debug-version of it separately in a debugger?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Debugging Webots with gdb, I get the exact same buffer overflow backtrace. My knowledge of gdb is limited though.

Comment: If you build with debug information (`-g` flag to GCC) then you will get more information, including filenames, function names and line numbers.